# Cannot access objects properties from another object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object

there are quite a lot of questions about this, so want to really know if I really cannot access other objects.
so let's say I have a missile class.

```
public class Missile extends MovieClip {

...

public function update(e:Event) {
    x += speed;

    if (notInScreen()) this.remove();

    for (var i in Main.instance.enemies) {
        if (hitTestObject(Main.instance.enemies[i])) {
            Main.instance.enemies[i].explode();
            this.remove();
        }
    }
}

public function remove() {
    this.parent.removeChild(this);
    ship.missiles.splice(0,1);      // <--- error
}

}
```

when it calls remove() function it tries to access a Ship class, I have placed Ship on stage and named its instance `ship`. But I still get error 1120: Access of undefined property ship.
Ship contains missiles array

```
public class Ship extends MovieClip {
    public var missiles:Array;
```

and Main contains enemies array

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {
    public var enemies:Array;
```

But `Main.instance.enemies` works, does that mean Main is not considered object, because it's just a document?
Or is there a way to workaround this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, what you are doing is bad practice. It's not the concern of the `Missile` object to remove itself from some data structure it is stored in before it destroys itself. I explain how to do it further below, but first the answer to your questions:

### Why that one thing doesn't work

> when it calls `remove()` function it tries to access a `Ship` class, I have placed Ship on stage and named its instance `ship`.

No, it doesn't access a `Ship` class.

1. Placing a ship on the stage creates an **object of that class**.
2. giving it an instance name creates **a variable** behind the scenes that is **a reference to the object**.

Maybe you just didn't know the right terminology when asking. But it is actually important to understand the difference between objects and classes.

If anything, you are trying to access an object of the `Ship` class, not the class itself. But still, the question stands why it doesn't work. And the answer simply is scope. The variable that is automatically declared with the instance name `ship` is declared on the main timeline (the `Main` class). And that's separate from the `Missile` class.

Take a look at what you are doing with the `missiles` array:

1. You declare it in the `Ship` class:

   ```
   public class Ship extends MovieClip {
       public var missiles:Array;
   ```
2. then you are trying to access it on an object of that class:

   ```
   ship.missiles
   ```
3. Now why do you think this is different for `ship` itself? You aren't expecting to directly access `missiles` either! Just like you `missiles` is in a certain object and you need that object in order get to `missiles`, the same holds true for `ship` itself: you need the object it lives in in order to access it.

You are basically asking "Hey, I give me the missiles of the ship!" and the answer would be "What ship?", because it is not clear what ship you mean. You never declared a variable `ship` in `Missile` class. **You** are making the shortcut in your head that it should somehow access the `ship` variable on the main timeline, but they are totally separate. Using same names in a project can trick you into such fallacies. You might as well try to access `bananas` in your `Missile` class, which won't work either, but is more obvious that it's something else.

### Why that other thing works

> But `Main.instance.enemies` works, does that mean `Main` is not considered object, because it's just a document?

There's no such thing as "just a document". `Main` is just another class. There are some specialities when it is used as a document class, but these aren't important here.

The reason why `Main.instance.enemies` works is as follows.
As I explained above, the variables live in objects (which in turn can again be referenced by variables that live in objects)

Hence you need a reference to an object in order to access the variables therein. The `Missile` class and thus none of the objects derived from it have this reference. (yeah, that's exactly what the error says).

The question is: how do you somehow get a reference to the `ship` object into a `Missile` object?

One decent way would be to pass a reference to the `Missile` constructor:

```
public class Missile extends MovieClip 
{
    private var ship:Ship;

    public function Missile(ship:Ship)
    {
        // error handling when ship is null is omitted here

        this.ship = ship;
    }
```

When you create an instance of the `Missile` class you pass the instance of `ship` to it:

```
var missile:Missile = new Missile(ship);
```

---

> **disclaimer** the following is to explain what's going on in your code. Just to be clear: this is very bad coding practice. You should **never** do it this way. The important thing to understand is not how it works. The important thing to understand is why it's bad.

There's the `static` keyword. Throughout this answer, all the variables defined by a class had to be accessed via an object created from that class.

If a variable is `static` it is not associated with an object, but the class itself. This is very interesting if something can't really be associated with a single object, like constants for example:

- `Math.PI`
- `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN`

which do not have to exist once per object. As a `static` variable of a class is associated with the class and not its objects, you access this `static` variable via the class name.

And this is where that other line comes into play:

> `Main.instance`

`instance` is accessed via the class name, which means that it is a `static` variable. That means that the `Main` class has a static variable (or possibly a function, too) that holds a reference to one of its objects.

Via the `static` mechanic, the reference to the object becomes globally available, because the class name is everywhere available. 
And this is how to sneakily get a reference to an object into a place where it shouldn't actually be in.
This is the bad part of this solution. Something that is globally available is not encapsulated very well. Everybody can access and modify it, which leads to abuse .

### How to do it

Again, the problem is that you need a reference to some object in order to do things with it, say for example do some collision detection.

The best thing to do is to first thing about what belongs where. While it is understandable that the `Ship` class has an array with all the `missiles`, it's a lot easier to have that array in `Main`, too. That's because the missile objects themselves are independent from the ship and they are added to the main time line anyway.

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {
    private var missiles:Array;
    private var enemies:Array;
```

If you think about it, the only real connection between the ship and the missiles is that the ship is the location where they are spawned.

Now you can easily spawn new `Missile` objects from the `Main` class and feed these objects into the array.

The most important thing is that you now have both arrays in one place and can **do the collision detection in `Main`**. there's no more confusion about what code should go where (should enemies test missiles or missiles test enemies?) It all happens where all references to objects are readily available. There's no abuse of `static`.

Comment: thats well explained, both seems to work, either I have to access ship directly from root or pass the ship as a variable or move everything to Main, which I don't want to, I still wish I could access it directly :D

Comment: @Waras you really don't want to access everything from everywhere directly.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you will get that error, because inside your `Missile` class you can not have access to an object in the stage like that.

To use your `ship` object, you can do :

```
MovieClip(root).ship.missiles.splice(0, 1);
```

OR, if your `Missile` is added to the stage, you can write it :

```
MovieClip(this.parent).ship.missiles.splice(0, 1);
```

Hope that can help.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you can do `Main.instance.enemies' but, you need to access stage.
you can you that by several ways:

1st way: when accessing from a display object:

```
this.parent;
```

2nd way: when accessing from an instance of a class:

```
this.root.stage
```

3rd way: pushing stage as an argument for class instance:

```
var class:Class1=new Class1(stage);
```

at the class:

```
public class class1{
    var mainStage:object;
    public function class1(stage:Object){
    mianStage=stage;
}
```

I  H☺ P E this helps !